# How to locate the element with text as My Name as per the HTML through Selenium

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I'm trying to find an element using selenium-webdriver with mocha in node.js. I'm doing pretty well but I have problem with a particular Google page that has poorly formatted HTML (many tags are not closed). Selenium doesn't like this. This is the standard Google click on your profile to sign in page. Here is an HTML sample. How do I wait for the page to load with my name and click on it? The only tag that seems to be closed is the li.

```
<div class="vdE7Oc f3GIQ"><p role="presentation" 
class="wpW1cb">My Name<p class="uRhzae" role="heading" 
aria-level="2" data-email="myemail@example.com"
>myemail@example.com</div></div></li>
```

Here's a list of things I've tried (among many others):

```
var profile = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.partialLinkText("My Name")));
var profile = await driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("My"));
var profile = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(., 'My Name')]"));
var profile = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css("p[email='myemail@example.com']")));
var profile = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//*[contains(., 'My Name')]")));
var profile = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.partialLinkText("My")));
var profile = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//p[@email='myemail@example.com']")));
```

Comment: Could you share the link?

Comment: Not exactly because Google changes it depending upon context and contains authentication information. This is the standard page Google offers when you use a third party app and after you enter your password and it asks you to select a profile before the "ALLOW" page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the HTML you have shared to locate the element with text as **myemail@example.com** you can use the following solution:

```
var profile = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//div//p[@role='heading' and @data-email='myemail@example.com']")));
```